# What is the lastest version of ADB in latest AOSP?

Tags: android, adb, version, android-source

I am trying to build the adb from latest AOSP source code tree, android-10.0.0_r20, which I found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+refs.
  The download and building went well, but I got adb at version 28.0.2, which is different from the latest adb version at 29.0.5, from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
 I also tried building from android-10.0.0_r15, I got adb 28.0.2 as well.
 So my question is: Is 28.0.2 is the most stable release of adb which recommended by Google? or I just didn't get the latest source code right?
 Any answers will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think there's anything wrong with your question, but i have to wonder if this question and any answers to it will stand the test of time :) it will have to be updated very frequently, although I guess that isn't up to me to decide really

Answer (score 1):

The latest version in AOSP master is 29.0.5

adb version is defined in system/core/adb/Android.mk, and read from development/sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template

Comment: Hi, Yong, Thanks for the comments. Can you elaborate a little? Because I did grabbing the master branch from scratch yesterday, the built adb is still 28.0.2, by run "adb --version". My questions: 1) The command I used to grab master: "repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest", is it wrong? 2) should I go editing the /sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template, to force compiling of adb to version 29.02?  Many thanks and appreciation for any response.

Comment: Check which adb is using. Try "out/host/linux-x86/bin/adb". If your local file is not the same as https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/sdk/plat_tools_source.prop_template, you may not sync rightly.

Answer (score 0):

After removing previous leftover .repo folder under my building directory, and running

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

again, to create new .repo folder, I can get the real master branch code and build latest adb (for now it's 29.0.5).